# Java Advantages of Converting Global Variables to Local Variables in Methods

Tags: java, variables, global-variables

I am working on an android launcher based on the stock launcher. I am just interested why are there lots of global variables converted to local variables in methods e.g.

```
final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
```

instead of just

```
mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
```

Is it some android thing or a general java rule? It makes no sense allocating a new `VelocityTracker` when it can be accessed directly.

**EDIT**
Yes this code is being repeated many times.

Comment: It might be a weird optimization, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602922/is-it-faster-to-access-final-local-variables-than-class-variables-in-java/6603067#6603067). Note I have no experience with Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be useful if you are using a field many times.  Some JVM and I assume Android VMs don't optimise access to fields as efficiently.

However it can be overused and I don't see the point if only accessed once.

It can also be useful of you are accessing a volatile field.  This ensures when you use that field many times you are taking about the same object. e.g.

```
volatile String text;

String text = this.text;
if(text != null)
    doSomething(text);
```

If you didn't use a local variable `text` could be non-null for the if statement and `null` for the doSomething().

Answer (score 1):

You are right, in your short example this assignment does not have any sense. But generally it is a good practice to minimize scope of variables. This allows you to concentrate on specific code that deals with specific variables.

Comment: How is it ever useful to assign a field to a local variable when the field is just as accessible as the variable?  How does this "minimize the scope of variables"?